# Type email is not showing in MVC site despite dataannotations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel, data-annotations

I have a MVC 4 website, where I want to have `type="email"` on a couple of input boxes. Now, normally I would just:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email, new { @type = "email" })
```

However, for some strange reason, the type is rendered as text.

Now, in my viewmodel I have:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Global), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ViewModel_input_required")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Global), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ViewModel_Account_display_email_not_valid", ErrorMessage = null)]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof (Global), Name = "ViewModel_Account_display_email")]
    [PlaceHolder(ResourceType = typeof(Global), Name = "ViewModel_Account_display_email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

Which, if I understand it correctly, should give it type email.

However, it is still type text.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: It would need to be `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @type = "email" })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke that is the correct answer! please make an answer, so I can mark it as so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add html attributes in MVC 4, you need to use `TextBoxFor()`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @type = "email" })
```

Note in MVC 5, you can use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "email" } })
```